# how to get highest input field value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get highest value of this field. How I can do this?

```
 <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="20" />
 <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="25" />
 <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="10" />
 <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="5" />
 <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="30" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure javascript:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="position[]"]');
var max =0;
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
   max =  Math.max(max , parseInt(inputs[i].value));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others may chime in with a vanilla solution, but if you are using jQuery here is a way you can do so

```
Array.max = function(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
};

var max = Array.max($('.input-text').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}));

console.log(max) // 30
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/okqjL22r/)

Answer (score 1):

Getting highest input value using [jQuery each](https://api.jquery.com/each/). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/axvvb7x3/1/)

```
var inputValue = -Infinity;
$("input:text").each(function() {
    inputValue = Math.max(inputValue, parseFloat(this.value));
});
alert(inputValue);
```

Comment: i cannot put on input there are also other other input  field too

Comment: You can use text selector

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="20" />
  <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="25" />
  <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="10" />
  <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="5" />
  <input type="text" style="width:20%;" class="input-text" name="position[]" value="30" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var myForm = document.forms.myForm;
var myControls = myForm.elements['position[]'];
var max = -Infinity;
for (var i = 0; i < myControls.length; i++) {
    if( max<parseInt(myControls[i]))
      max=parseInt(myControls[i]);
}
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxVal = 0;
$('input[name="position[]"]').each(function(){
    maxVal = Math.max(maxVal , parseInt($(this).val()));
});
alert(maxVal);
```