# Get the input id of an input element with the highest numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few input fields with class name `scores`, their ids are random and for sure the input fields are dynamic but with the same class name.

```
<input type="text" class="scores" id="1dhs3d" value="50">

<input type="text" class="scores" id="ae34bd" value="100">

<input type="text" class="scores" id="6ydbbd" value="15">
```

How do i get the id (in this case, it's ae34bd) of input that has the highest value.

Note: it's possible i have elements with more than one "same high score"

I have tried this:

```
var max_=[];
$('.scores').each(function(){ max_.push( $(this).val() ); });

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, max_);
```

With this, can only get the highest value but i need to know the id of element that has that highest value.

Comment: What would you want to happen if you have multiple inputs with the same max score?

Comment: This is very close (if not identical) of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723040/how-to-get-highest-input-field-value-in-javascript/30723115
 and 
https://api.jquery.com/attr/ <- the attributes

Comment: @andrei040191 thanks.  It worked. But curious if that will work if two elements has same highest value

Comment: @DBS if possible, i should be able to loop through them(i.e multiple same highest value)

Comment: I will check that @Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using sorting from the Array object:

```js
let scores = Array.from($(".scores"));

let sortedElements = scores.sort((a, b) => parseInt($(b).val()) - parseInt($(a).val()));

let $max = $(sortedElements[0]);

console.log("Element id with highest score: #" + $max.attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="scores" id="1dhs3d" value="50">

<input type="text" class="scores" id="ae34bd" value="100">

<input type="text" class="scores" id="6ydbbd" value="15">


<input type="text" class="scores" id="6ydb2d" value="15">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvkh12s6/

Answer (score 2):

As I know you got the answer already, But I have done this in JavaScript and to get if there are multiple fields with the same highest value.

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('scores');
    elements = [...elements];
    console.log(...elements)
    
    let max = Math.max.apply(Math, elements.map(e=>Number(e.value)))
  console.log(max)
    
    let allMaxIds = elements.filter(e=>{
      return max === Number(e.value);
            
   }).map(e=> {return {id:e.id,score:Number(e.value)}});
    
    console.log(allMaxIds)
```

```html
<input type="text" class="scores" id="1dhs3d" value="50">
<input type="text" class="scores" id="ae34bd" value="100">
<input type="text" class="scores" id="ae34bb" value="100">
<input type="text" class="scores" id="6ydbbd" value="15">
```

Comment: @Theconcise welcome, and I have simplified it a bit reducing sort and for loop